# Where do I add the required positional argument in this Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to work with individual customer data within the customers view, so that I can display it on the aggregated list, but am continually running into the following error:

**TypeError**

*customers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'customer_id'*

**View**

```
def customers(request, customer_id):
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('last_name')
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)

    # ... snip

    context = {'customers': customer}
    
    return render(request, 'app/customers.html', context)
```

**Model**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # ... snip


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.last_name.title()}, {self.first_name.title()}"
```

**URL Pattern**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... snip
    path('customers/', views.customers, name='customers'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the url patterns for the customer like this so the from url_patterns  referencing to your views customer_id

```
   urlpatterns = [
        # ... snip
        path('customers/<int:customer_id>/', views.customers, name='customers'),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks... I seem to have this much working now, but have come to realize I am looking at the problem the wrong way.